# How to preserve column heading while using .split() function

Tags: python, pandas

My goal below is to create 1 single column of all the individual words of each string in the 'Name' column.

Although I am achieving this, I am losing the column header on `df = df['Name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)` . I would like to preserve the header if possible so that I can refer to it later in the script.

I am also ending up with multiple indexes, which is fine, but if there is a way to not have this, it would be great.

Any help is appreciated greatly.  Thank you

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Tom Wilson', 'nick snyder', 'krish moham', 'jack oconnell']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df['Name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)

df = df.stack(dropna=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: What's your desired output exactly? I know how to do the column part, but I'm not sure what index you want.

Comment: Maybe you just need to drop the index with `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom Wilson', 'nick snyder', 'krish moham', 'jack oconnell']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df['Name'].str.split(' ').explode().to_frame()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       Name
0       Tom
0    Wilson
1      nick
1    snyder
2     krish
2     moham
3      jack
3  oconnell
```